# Using CSS to style labels pointing to elements with a certain attribute

Tags: css, unobtrusive-validation

I am using unobtrusive validation in an ASP.Net MVC3 app.  I would like to style the **label elements** associated with required elements in a certain way.

My concern is not to tweak the visual indicators around the required field itself, but to modify the appearance of a **different** element based on the attributes of **this** element.

Now, I believe it would be possible to style the elements themselves just with CSS by using a CSS rule whose selector applied to all elements with the `[data-val-required]` attribute.  It would look something like this:

```
input[data-val-required] { color: red; }
```

But is it possible to style the labels?  To say (with a CSS selector) that a CSS rule applies to all **label elements** whose `for` attribute points to an `input` element that has the `[data-val-required]` attribute?

I'm currently applying styling with a little bit of jQuery currently, and it works nicely.  But it would be even nicer if I could just set up a CSS rule and be done with it.

Comment: what does ur jquery selector look like?

Comment: of course it's possible to style the labels, but you'll have to show us some code...

Comment: @BassamMehanni  My jQuery uses more than one selector:  I look at labels with the *for* attribute, retrieve the element referenced by the *for*, and check it for [data-val-required].

Comment: @ptriek Be happy to; do you want to see the HTML or the CSS?

Comment: both, preferably - and the jQuery too.. If you could set up a stripped version in jsfiddle.com - that would be the easiest way to provide you an answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Required Field Indicator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650637/asp-net-mvc-required-field-indicator)

Comment: @Divi I disagree.  I have modified the question to clarify how it differs from the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get there from here. As @vlgalik says, the only CSS options are selectors that are 1) not supported on some browsers, and 2) have limited ability to find other elements, forcing you to construct your markup to comply.

So, your current solution -- use JQuery to find the labels and their corresponding inputs -- is your best bet.

However, I'd approach your jQuery solution in the opposite direction: first find all the inputs matching `input[data-val-required]`, and for each of those, get its ID, then select the corresponding label: `label[for="<id-from-input>"]` -- that seems like it will be less work. But that's an optimization;  if you don't have a lot of labels and inputs on the page, either direction will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This [jsfiddle example is using CSS3 selectors](http://jsfiddle.net/fvgre/), but there is a downside that the label must follow after input element in the HTML (can be placed before using addition CSS like in example).

Much simpler and effective would be to give the label element class attribute like:

```
<label class="required">
```

or to place the label input pair in div element:

```
<div class="required">
  <label for="input1">Label 1</label>
  <input id="input1" ... />
</div>
```

and apply desired CSS styling by simply using:

```
.required label {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean about this being simpler.  However, what I was hoping for was a solution that was based (ultimately) on the automatically-generated data-val-required attribute and didn't require me, the programmer, to do anything differently between the required and the optional fields.  Hence my hope for a CSS style.  (There's also the matter that some fields are only required if certain other fields contain other values, so I would need to remove or add styles or elements.  A CSS style would adapt automatically if the attributes of the element were to change).

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave should be very close to what you would need to do. Try using this:

```
input[for=data-val-required]{}
```

This selector is based off of the attributes of a given tag. That should give you what you are looking for.