# Optimize web page styling with cshtml/c#/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, razor, computer-science

I am using a combination of cshtml/c#/css/javascript to create a web page, which I am completely new to, so any tip would be welcome.

C# files creates a partial class, with this being a sample snippet

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name *")]        //First Name * is displayed on actual page
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```

cshtml file creates all necessary containers, labels, and paragraphs.
css contains all styles.
javascript enhances webpage functionality.

So, here is a deal: I need to add *'s, which should be all red for all required elements. I can go through all possible pages and manually add those to every element, but I thought if it is possible to optimize the code.

Is it possible to create something like a pseudocode below?

```
if variable has a required flag set to it //from c# file
    add stylized red * next to the label
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

## UPDATE

I have modified code from articles I have provided below, however, here is another problem I keep stumbling upon. Here is a modified code from my helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorEntryFor<TModel, TValue>(
      this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
  {
     return BuildFormEntry(html.LabelWithRequiredMarkerFor(expression),
         html.EditorFor(expression), html.ValidationMessageFor(expression));
     //return BuildFormEntry(html.LabelWithRequiredMarkerFor(expression),
     //    html.TextAreaFor(expression), html.ValidationMessageFor(expression));
  }

private static MvcHtmlString LabelWithRequiredMarkerFor<TModel, TValue>(
      this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
      Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
  {
     var label = html.LabelFor(expression);
     if (ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData).IsRequired)
     {
        label = new MvcHtmlString(label.ToString().Substring(0, label.ToString().Length - 8).Trim() +
            "<span style=\"color:red\" class=\"required-marker\">*</span></label>");
     }
     return label;
  }

private static MvcHtmlString BuildFormEntry(
      MvcHtmlString label, MvcHtmlString input, MvcHtmlString validation)
  {
     return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"editor-label\">" + label + "</div>\n" +
     "<div class=\"editor-field\">" + input + validation + "</div>\n\n");
     //return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"editor-label\">" + label + "</div>\n");
  }
```

The method call is exactly like LabelFor:

```
Html.EditorEntryFor(model => model.Project.FirstName)
//**equals to**
Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.FirstName)
```

Now I want the expression inside EditorEntryFor was like the following:

```
Html.EditorEntryFor(model => model.Project.FirstName, new { @title = "Enter firstname." })
```

However, the helper only accepts a single parameter expression, and I want the expression value to be equal to **model => model.Project.FirstName, new { @title = "Enter firstname." })**

However, Visual Studio always thinks that I try entering the second parameter.
Is there a way to force Expression to think that "," is a part of expression instead of second parameter? Thus far, it looks like none of the normal string manipulations will do the trick =(

**Thank you all very much in advance!**

Comment: Yes, there are many libraries. See [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) for an example

Comment: You can use reflection to get custom attributes from classes/properties and modify the content as you need.

Comment: If you need asterisk sign to mark required fields, I found similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650637/asp-net-mvc-required-field-indicator, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940506/how-can-i-modify-labelfor-to-display-an-asterisk-on-required-fields. The most important thing you need is having some CSS selectors to set behaviour of required fields like `content: "*"; font-weight: bold; color: red`.

Comment: Thank you all very much for such rapid responses! I was trying my best to first check that there were no duplicates of such question, it looks like I still need to learn how to do the research properly. Nevertheless, I will study all three possibilities and check which one work the best for me!

Comment: In addition to already provided solutions, I have found a couple very useful articles, which tremendously helped me with implementation of what I need: [html helper with required fields](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/07/automatic-marking-of-required-fields-with-editorentryfor/), [html helper](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/06/drying-mvc-forms-with-an-editorentryfor-helper/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to already provided solutions, I have found a couple very useful articles, which tremendously helped me with implementation of what I need: [html helper with required fields](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/07/automatic-marking-of-required-fields-with-editorentryfor/), [html helper](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/06/drying-mvc-forms-with-an-editorentryfor-helper/)